# Find item from FileScanner by index in Groovy

Tags: collections, groovy, closures

I am trying to find an item from a FileScanner (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ant/FileScanner.html) for a given index in Groovy. The following closure works, but I am not sure how I can make it "return" the file name:

```
def getFileNameByIndex = { int fileIndex ->
  scanner.eachWithIndex { fileName, index ->
      if (index == fileIndex)
          println "${index}. Filename ${fileName}"
          // how do I return the fileName here?
  }
}
```

I should be able to call it as: getFileNameByIndex(10), where 10 is the index.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the inputs, and what you'd expect the output to be?

Comment: Input is a list of file names. E.g. [/usr/file1, /usr/file2, /usr/file3]. I am trying to retrieve the file name given the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
def getFileNameByIndex = { int fileIndex ->
  list[fileIndex]?.fileName
}
```

As it's a scanner, not a list, I think you'd need:

```
def getFileNameByIndex = { int fileIndex ->
    int idx = 0
    scanner.find { idx++ == fileIndex }?.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Sorry, there was a little correction I had to make in the posting. It is not a List but a FileScanner object I am dealing with here.

Comment: That did not seem to work. Getting this:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: fileName

Comment: @naspras It's probably `name` then, not `fileName`, I'm not sure what FileScanner's iterator returns...

Comment: However, "name" strips off the path from the filepath and just returns the file name. I am not sure what property to use instead so to return the entire file path. FileScanner holds the entire filepaths.

Comment: @naspras Right, so it must be `java.io.File`s it's iterating over...  Try `.canonicalPath`

Comment: Excellent @tim_yates! Thanks so much. I was trying to find the iterator type, and you are quicker :). +1